# How to make a function work within string in Excel?

Tags: excel

Im preparing a big excel sheet, where I need to use a function.

```
eg:=LEFT(....) (this works as expected.)
```

But when I try to manipulate a column like;

```
="this is a string ,LEFT(....)"
```

it is not working. means it is not printing LEFT function value in the string.
How should I make that to work?

Comment: You can't put a formula inside quotes and expect it to work. you need something like `="this is a string"&LEFT(...)` or `=CONCATENATE("this is a string",LEFT(...))`

Comment: `="this is a string , "&LEFT(....)` You need to concatenate the function's result onto the string literal

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks

Comment: @user11138753 thanks that works

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Can you make that an answer? That example you gave is a great example of when to use `CONCATENATE()` or just `&`.  I've never thought about it before, but have dozens of formulas personally that are like, `="123"&[some formula]&" more text"` that would be much clearer in my opinion if I used `CONCATENATE()` instead. I just had a revelation :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a formula inside quotes and expect it to work.

You need something like

```
="this is a string"&LEFT(...)
```

or

```
=CONCATENATE("this is a string",LEFT(...))
```